# Запуск QSalp для Quik под Wine на linux mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, wine

У меня под Wine установлен Quik. Я установила QScalp, но он не запускается. Ни в терминале, ни в Nemo, ни под root. 
В nemo запускаю с помощью wine, но ничего не происходит

В терминале запускаю с помощью команды

```
wine start 'C:\QScalp\QSalp.exe'
```

В ответ получаю:

```
000d:err:menubuilder:convert_to_native_icon error 0x80004005 creating bitmap encoder
000d:err:wincodecs:PngEncoder_CreateInstance Failed writing PNG because unable to find libpng12.so.0
000d:fixme:ole:CoCreateInstanceEx no instance created for interface {00000103-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94} of class {27949969-876a-41d7-9447-568f6a35a4dc}, hres is 0x80004005
000d:err:menubuilder:convert_to_native_icon error 0x80004005 creating bitmap encoder
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
Приложение не может быть запущено или нет ассоциированных с типом данного документа приложений.
Вызов ShellExecuteEx провалился: Файл не найден.
```

libpng12.so.0 я установила, но он все равно на него ругается.

Версия wine 4.0.1 stable
Linux mint 19

Установлен Net framework 4.5, Пакет библиотек VC6RedistSetup, которые требуются для работы.

Скажите, в каком направлении ещё копать? Quik работает замечательно.

Comment: после установки libpng12-0 ошибка осталась?

Answer (score 1):

Wine обычно требует 32х разрядных версий библиотек. Установить так:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt update
apt install libpng12-0:i386
```

Comment: Не помогло, ошибка та же самая

Answer (score 0):

Решение **eri** скорее всего поможет, но если нет, то вот мой небольшой скрипт, создающий 32х битный префикс и устанавливающий самые необходимые библиотеки:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# удаляет текущий дефолтный префикс и создаёт новый 32х-битный
rm -rf ~/.wine
WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot

# можно поэкспериментировать
# winetricks glsl=disabled csmt=off
# winetricks glsl=enabled csmt=on

# много где нужно, редко что ломает (но я гарантий не даю)
winetricks mfc42 d3dx9 vcrun6 vcrun6sp6 vb6run vcrun2003 vcrun2005 vcrun2008 vcrun2010 vcrun2012 vcrun2013 vcrun2015 directplay msxml3 msxml4 msxml6 flash

# иногда нужно, но вполне может только добавить проблем
# winetricks ie8 corefonts tahoma

# следующий код можно раскоментировать для удаления mono и установки .net
# wine uninstaller --remove '{E45D8920-A758-4088-B6C6-31DBB276992E}'
# winetricks dotnet452
# winetricks win7

# в финале поправьте настройки на своё усмотрение
winecfg

# удаяет мусорные лаунчеры вроде открытия текстовых файлов в виндовом блокноте
rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/wine*
```

Чтобы при смене дефолтного префикса не терять свои программы, можно подключить отдельную директорию в виде диска `D` и устанавливать свой софт туда:

[image: пример]

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что после выполнения скрипта, мне придется все программы заново устанавливать?

Comment: @MadwomaZ Да. Он создаёт префикс с нуля, по этому всё что установлено на диске С: будет потеряно. 32х-битный префикс лучше совместим с библиотеками. Winetricks, например, рекомендуют использовать его прежде чем отправлять репорты.